# Simple Encryption Program Malfunction

Tags: java, encryption

My encryption program is supposed to use a two character key (16 bit, 8 bits per character) to encrypt and decrypt a text file. The formula of the encryption and decryption is given by the same formula:

```
Encrypted(M) = M ^ (K||K||...)
and
Decrypted(M) = M ^ (K||K||...)
```

Where M is the content of the text file, ^ is exclusive or, and K is the key. The key is concatenated until it is the same size as the text file content.

The encrypt() method below seems to work, but when I try to use the decrypt() method some words come out fine, but most of it is gibberish. The two methods are identical except for some variable naming. I would really appreciate some feedback on whats going wrong.

```
  public static void encrypt() throws IOException {
    String path = System.console().readLine("Enter the file to encrypt: ");
    String baseKey = System.console().readLine("\nEnter two characters for the key: ");

    FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

    String preCrypt = ""; // preCrypt is the file, read as a string, before        encyption.
    String line = "";

    while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
      preCrypt = preCrypt + line;
    }

    buffReader.close();

    int numOfBytes = preCrypt.length();

    // If the number of bytes in the file is odd, add a space to the end.
    if(numOfBytes % 2 != 0) {
      preCrypt = preCrypt + " ";
      numOfBytes++;
}

    // Adjust the key so that it is the same length as the file.
    String key = baseKey;
     while (key.length() != numOfBytes)
    {
      key = key + baseKey;
    }

    StringBuilder decrypted = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; i++) // Perform the encryption.
    {
      decrypted.append((char)(preCrypt.charAt(i) ^ key.charAt(i)));
    }

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(path); // Write changes to file.
    out.println(decrypted.toString());
    out.close();
    }

  public static void decrypt() throws IOException {
    String path = System.console().readLine("Enter the file to decrypt: ");
    String baseKey = System.console().readLine("\nEnter two characters for the key: ");

    FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

    String preCrypt = ""; // preCrypt is the file, read as a string, before decyption.
    String line = "";

    while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
     preCrypt = preCrypt + line;
   }

    buffReader.close();

    int numOfBytes = preCrypt.length();

    // If the number of bytes in the file is odd, add a space to the end.
    if(numOfBytes % 2 != 0) {
      preCrypt = preCrypt + " ";
      numOfBytes++;
    }

    // Adjust the key so that it is the same length as the file.
    String key = baseKey;
    while (key.length() != numOfBytes)
    {
      key = key + baseKey;
    }

    StringBuilder encrypted = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; i++)// Perform the decryption.
    {
      encrypted.append((char)(preCrypt.charAt(i) ^ key.charAt(i)));
    }

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(path); // Write changes to the file.
    out.println(encrypted.toString());
    out.close();
  }
```

Comment: Convert input character data to bytes using UTF-8 encoding. The key should two bytes, not two characters. The cipher should be a sequence of bytes, not characters.

Comment: This. It's probably because of the byte/char confusion here. You can't safely XOR a character. Treat the file as a byte stream using `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, *not* `Reader` and `Writer`.

Comment: As the functionality of encryption and decryption is completely the same, you should only have one function.

Comment: Thanks. Per everyones comments, I've overhauled my code to have one method that uses ByteArrayInputStream/ByteArrayOutputStream, and an array of UTF-8 bytes . It also seems to be working and executing much faster.